# Job stealing of new nodes using Ignite compute

Tags: java, ignite, grid-computing

I'm trying to compute a batch of tasks on an Ignite cluster where nodes use a jobstealing policy.

Everything works fine except when a new node join the cluster while the batch have already been initiated : this node seems to not be able to steal any task of the batch already running. I get the following message :

```
'SEVERE: Failed to send job stealing message to node: TcpDiscoveryNode [...]'
```

I think that there is an already existing issue described here : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-1267

This issue seems to have a fix in the thread, but in Ignite 2.6.0 the problem is still here.

Here is my compute configuration :

```
    JobStealingCollisionSpi spi = new JobStealingCollisionSpi();
    spi.setWaitJobsThreshold(1);
    spi.setMessageExpireTime(1000);
    spi.setMaximumStealingAttempts(10);
    spi.setActiveJobsThreshold(1);
    spi.setStealingEnabled(true);

    JobStealingFailoverSpi failoverSpi = new JobStealingFailoverSpi();
    cfg.setCollisionSpi(spi);
    cfg.setFailoverSpi(failoverSpi);

    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

EDIT : tried to reproduce it, but now it seems to work as intended. This is a really strange behavior !

EDIT2 : Managed to randomly reproduce the problem, here is the stack :

```
class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to send message to remote node: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=f54e6f43-620c-418d-a840-bce51ad1f5f5, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.36.3.4, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/10.36.3.4:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=3, intOrder=3, lastExchangeTime=1543917557221, loc=false, ver=2.6.0#20180710-sha1:669feacc, isClient=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2718)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2651)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:1643)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToCustomTopic(GridIoManager.java:1703)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter$1.send(GridManagerAdapter.java:422)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.collision.jobstealing.JobStealingCollisionSpi.checkIdle(JobStealingCollisionSpi.java:1074)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.collision.jobstealing.JobStealingCollisionSpi.onCollision(JobStealingCollisionSpi.java:722)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.collision.GridCollisionManager.onCollision(GridCollisionManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.handleCollisions(GridJobProcessor.java:712)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.access$3000(GridJobProcessor.java:111)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobDiscoveryListener.onEvent(GridJobProcessor.java:2008)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.eventstorage.GridEventStorageManager$LocalListenerWrapper.onEvent(GridEventStorageManager.java:1384)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.eventstorage.GridEventStorageManager.notifyListeners(GridEventStorageManager.java:873)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.eventstorage.GridEventStorageManager.notifyListeners(GridEventStorageManager.java:858)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.eventstorage.GridEventStorageManager.record0(GridEventStorageManager.java:341)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.eventstorage.GridEventStorageManager.record(GridEventStorageManager.java:307)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryWorker.recordEvent(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2703)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryWorker.body0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2920)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryWorker.body(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2732)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=f54e6f43-620c-418d-a840-bce51ad1f5f5, addrs=[/10.36.3.4:47100, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100]]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3422)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2958)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2841)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2692)
    ... 20 more
    Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to address [addr=/10.36.3.4:47100, err=Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3425)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$HandshakeException: Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.safeTcpHandshake(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3737)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3276)
        ... 23 more
    Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to address [addr=/10.36.3.4:47100, err=Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3425)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$HandshakeException: Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.safeTcpHandshake(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3737)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3276)
        ... 23 more
    Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to address [addr=/10.36.3.4:47100, err=Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3425)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$HandshakeException: Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.safeTcpHandshake(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3737)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3276)
        ... 23 more
    Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to address [addr=/10.36.3.4:47100, err=Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3425)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$HandshakeException: Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.safeTcpHandshake(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3737)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3276)
        ... 23 more
    Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to address [addr=/10.36.3.4:47100, err=Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3425)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$HandshakeException: Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.safeTcpHandshake(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3737)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3276)
        ... 23 more
```

Comment: Please provide the full error message along with a stack trace.

Comment: Just tried to reproduce it, but now it seems to work as intended. This is a really strange behavior

Comment: Managed to randomly reproduce the problem, so I added the stack !

Comment: The error message tells us, that one node failed to send a message to another node because the network connection has been closed. Most probably, the destination node has just left topology. Do you see any functional consequences of it?

Comment: On the functional side it depends ! On Nov 28 when I posted the first message, it managed to finish the computation of the jobs given. But today, as it was reproduced, all the nodes got communication problems so the jobs were never finished.

Comment: Communication problems lead to this exception, not the opposite. It's most probably caused by network issues.

Comment: I also think that its a communication problem.
My ignite cluster is running on GCP Kubernetes Engine, I've started to see these problems on Nov 28.
However It is strange that it is produced by the same job batch. could it be a possible out of memory error of a computation task in an ignite node that causes this behavior ?

Comment: Do you see the out of memory error on any nodes? If yes, then it definitely can cause failure of communication between nodes.

Comment: Can you share your compute section and the closure? I am facing the same issue and haven't been able to get the job stealing work. I have posted a question and it has the code which I have for Closure and Compute invocation. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948793/job-stealing-configuration-not-working-in-apache-ignite